# $directory result Null in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, directory, vmware

I made a file upload in codeigniter, but in the controller I set $ directory = './assets/images/'; unreadable on vmware.

please help, here is my controller

```
public function tambahfotoproses()
    {
        $variable = 'foto'; //variable name dari form
        $directory = './assets/images/'; //direktori
        $allowed_file = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png|JPG|GIF|PNG|JPEG'; //file yang diizinkan dibatasi dengan tanda
        $upload['detail'] = $this->m_admin->uploadfile($variable,$directory,$allowed_file); //proses dengan modul insertfile
        var_dump($upload); die();
        /* to upload file */
        $filename = $upload['detail']['file_name'];


        if ($filename != "")
        {
            $data = array(
                'foto' => $filename,
                'person_nm' => $this->input->post('person_nm'),
                'pengupload' => $this->input->post('pengupload'),
                'tgl' => $this->input->post('tgl')
            );
            $insert = $this->db->insert('eregister_foto',$data);

        } else {
            $data = array(
                'foto' => $filename,
                'person_nm' => $this->input->post('person_nm'),
                'pengupload' => $this->input->post('pengupload'),
                'tgl' => $this->input->post('tgl')
            );
            $insert = $this->db->insert('eregister_foto',$data);
        }

        redirect('index.php/admin/foto_dr');
    }
```

I deliberately gave `var_dump ()` to find out the results of $ upload
the result is array (1) {["detail"] => int (0)}
photo not uploaded

and here is my modals.php
/*AKSI UPLOAD FILE*/

```
function uploadfile($var,$dir,$all){
    $new_name = $this->input->post('person_nm');
    $config2=array(
        'image_library' => 'gd2',
        'upload_path' => $dir."/dokter/", //lokasi gambar akan di simpan
        'allowed_types' => $all, //ekstensi gambar yang boleh di unggah
        'create_thumb' => TRUE,
        'max_size' => '2048', //batas maksimal ukuran gambar
        'file_name' => $new_name
    );

    $this->load->library('upload');
    $this->upload->initialize($config2);
    if ($this->upload->do_upload($var))
    {
        return $this->upload->data();
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

i've try to rewrite folder "dokter" too, and still can't work

Comment: so give read / write permission to `./assets/images/` also check that uploaded file is there in that directory or not.

Comment: you mean at folder "assets" and "images" ? both of it ?

Comment: no only images folder need that permission

Comment: i try with permission which code of Octal "0777", can't work, please advice

Comment: 777 means you have all the permission, so try to upload image manually in images folder, if it is successfull then problem in your code and show your model function code

Comment: sorry, but stil can't work

Comment: show the code of your modal file

Comment: here is the link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57409532/directory-result-null-in-codeigniter)

Comment: print the upload error in else conditon  `echo $this->upload->display_errors()` before `return 0` check if any error.

Comment: you mean at controllers.php ?